# Assigning a button tag based on random items from an array

Tags: c#, arrays, button, random, tags

```
{
  var buttonnameString = new List<string> { "button1", ... , "button12" };
  for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
  {
    // Random car assignment to button 
    Random myRandom = new Random();
    var carString = new List<string> { "Camaro", ... , "Model T" };
    int index = myRandom.Next(carString.Count);
    var name = carString[index];
    carString.RemoveAt(index);
    Tag = name.ToString(); 
  }
}
```

In advance, thank you for any help that is provided. I'm a first year C# student so I know I have a lot to learn, but I've exhausted the extent of my google skills on trying to get this to work. 
What I'm trying to do, is make a matching program. This program will have 12 buttons, labeled "button1", "button2"....etc. When the button is clicked, it will display it's tag, which is provided from a random array. I've gotten the random feature to work on assigning only a single buttons tag. Where I'm hung up at, is repeating this to all the buttons in a groupbox. I've tried the foreach venue, but couldn't get it to work successfully. Eventually I tried other methods as well. Below is where I've stopped at as I'm unsure on where to go. The two major questions that I have are

1. How do I assign the random string to a wildcard button tag?
2. What is the best way to accomplish randomly assigning 12 car names, to 12 buttons? The use of two arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
  var numOfButtons = 12;
  var matchingButtonIndex = 0;
  // Random car assignment to button 
  Random myRandom = new Random();
  var buttons = new List<Button> { button1, ... , button12 };
  var carString = new List<string> { "Camaro", ... , "Model T" };
  while (matchingButtonIndex < numOfButtons)
  {
    int index = myRandom.Next(carString.Count);
    var name = carString[index];
    if (name != null)
    {
      buttons[matchingButtonIndex].Tag = name;
      carString[index] = null;
      matchingButtonIndex = matchingButtonIndex + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Notice I have changed the button names array to an array of buttons. I have also emptied out the `carString` as I find unused car names.

Comment: Thank you! Much help and makes sense once I see it in black and white.

Comment: Remember when programming, always think about adding more variables (space), loops (iterations), and if (conditions) to solve a problem. Computers are good at using them compare to human. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over buttons is easy when you iterate through the form's Controls

```
var carString = new List<string> { "Camaro", "Mini Cooper", "Porsche 944", "Ford Focus", "Chevy Blazer", "Model T", "Camaro", "Mini Cooper", "Porsche 944", "Ford Focus", "Chevy Blazer", "Model T" };

    foreach(Control c in Controls)
    {
        if (c is Button)
        {
            Random myRandom = new Random();
            int index = myRandom.Next(carString.Count);
            c.Tag = carString[index];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Each of the 12 buttons that I have, have the following code assigned to them "button2.Text = button2.Tag.ToString();" Upon pressing each button, and utilizing the code supplied above, the name of the button doesn't pull the random tag.